# Cross-Origin Error while trying to log

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

When I was trying to log, I got a Cross-Origin Error. Below is the complete error message.

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://10.138.31.41:8243/insurance/1.0.0/i_customers/q?{%22username%22:%22q%22}. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.

Comment: Try paste https://10.138.31.41:8243/insurance/1.0.0/i_customers into your browser and accept cert

Answer (score 0):

When your request is not sent from the same origin, browsers will send an options-request to the target server to make sure, whether the target server allows requests from the foreign origin with given http-method and headers for the requested endpoint.

It seems like the target server blocks your requests, so you should make sure, that the cors-response from your target server is adjusted (meaning it includes an "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"-Header listing the url your request comes from) or not rejected (maybe your request gets rejected, because you are requesting via https but ip-based, to the certificate is not accepted). If this is not possible, you could "bypass" the Same-Origin-Policy-Check from your browser with a jsonp-request (only http-get) or by sending the request over a reverse-proxy.